# Why is this affair-filled solution to Love Revolution incorrect?

Tags: storyteller

I am on the final chapter (Novels) of Storyteller. Stage 4 (Love Revolution) of this chapter has the title "*Knight and Maid Murder the Monarchs and Have an Affair*".

I arranged the panels so the Maid has an affair with the King and kills the Queen, while the Knight has an affair with the Queen and kills the King. However, despite matching the title, the solution didn't count.

[image]

Why was my solution incorrect? Is there some hidden requirement I'm missing? Do the Knight and the Maid need to have an affair with each other instead of with the King and Queen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Knight and the Maid need to have an affair with each other.

Light solution spoilers:

> The Knight and the Maid can have an affair with each other after both the King and Queen are dead.

Full solution spoilers:

> Arrange the panels as follows: Queen sees the King and the Maid have an affair. The Queen kidnaps the Maid. King rescues the Maid. King Kidnaps the Queen. Knight rescues the Queen. Knight kills the King. Maid kills the King. Knight and Maid have an affair.
>
>  [image]